# Clojure Recipe for Dynamic Channels/pub-sub

Tags: clojure, core.async

I'm looking for a way to dynamically build up subscribers to publications using core.async (or anything that will work).

Problem: I have messages that I need to process based on the `:sender` of the message. Each message will be operated on by the same function, but **the point is** that each sender's messages will be processed in order, one at a time -- multiple topics based on the `:sender` key with one consumer each. I also need a way to limit the number of active consumers across all subscriptions to keep resource utilization down.

My thought is that I would have a `pub` channel:

```
(def in-chan (chan))
(def publication (pub in-chan :sender))
```

But I want to be able to ensure that there is always a subscriber as new senders are brought online. I'm open to better facilities as long as the code stays small and simple.

**Question**: Is there an idiomatic way of ensuring there is a subscriber for a specific publication before sending the message? How do I coordinate all the consumers of each subscription to use a shared thread pool?

**EDIT**: I’ve figured out how to coordinate the work using a thread pool and single consumer per topic. I think for checking if a sub exists I will use a ref of a map to store the topic name to the sub. If the ref doesn’t have an entry for a subscriber, I’d create one and add it to the map; next I’ll register the subscriber to the publication and publish the message. The purpose of this question is to see if there’s a better way to spin up and keep track of subscribers for dynamically created topics.

Comment: What is your question specifically?

Comment: @OlegTheCat Edited to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with is to use a `ref`:

```
(def registration (ref {}))
```

This registration is used by the thread that writes to the publication channel just before writing:

```
(defn register
  [registration topic-name]
  (dosync
    (let [r (ensure registration)
          something-to-track :tracked] ;; In my case, I'm keeping track of a channel
      (when-not (get r topic-name)
        (alter registration assoc topic-name something-to-track)
        something-to-track))))
```

Whenever we need to publish a message we can use this function to "register" a new subscriber. If one did not previously exist, it will return `something-to-track`. In my case, it is a channel that I will subsequently call `sub` on. If it is `nil`, I can ignore it. To truly not miss messages in a concurrent environment I would need to do something in the transaction (need to understand if `ensure` would protect me by giving exclusive access to the `registration` across threads) but my pipeline is so small that I can write to the `pub` single-threaded.